# JavaScript Unable to autofill Username and Password Fields

Tags: javascript, element, autofill

Im trying to have some fields in a webpage autofill by adding some javascript to the end of the webpage but that does not seem to be working properly.
When testing on jsfiddle.net it work, but on the actual webpage (not owned by me) it does not work.

Is there another way I should be filling in the elements or does the webpage some other way managing how that is entered?

the webpage i'm trying to have username and password filled in on is:

The code im using is as follows:

```
var jusername = "Testing"; // Username
var jpassword = "Passwtrtyord"; // Password
var loginBtn = document.getElementById('btnSignin'); // Login button on page

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
document.getElementById('txtEmailid').value = jusername // fill in the username
document.getElementById('txtPassword').value = jpassword; // fill in the password
var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);             
    document.getElementById('btnSignin').dispatchEvent (evt); // Click the "Sign In" button by dispatching an event
})
```

Comment: These fields are handled specially by most browsers for security reasons and to provide their own autofilling based on user profiles and such. I realize your example is somewhat contrived, but you shouldn't have access to this information prior to entry. Where are you retrieving it from?

Comment: F12 when I get to the webpage, I highlight the element and it brings me to the source element.

Comment: How does that apply?

Comment: Im not sure what you are getting at. What information do you need?

Comment: I'm asking how the script could know what values to autofill and where those values would come from in your actual code. This has nothing to do with the F12 development tools .

Comment: When you go to the page I need this for, I press F12 and inspect the elements. when I select the text field for the username i get <input name="txtEmailid" type="text" id="txtEmailid" class="input100" autocomplete="false" placeholder="Enter Email id">

Comment: Maybe you need to restate your question. I don't see how that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Im confused. I want to have some java script fill in some text fields after the page has loaded. I would need to know the id of the field i want to fill in... then have the JS click the button.... not sure what you think im attempting other than what the question actually says..

Comment: Are you saying you want to run this script against an arbitrary page by pasting it in dev tools?

Comment: Yes, but the page is specifically the one posted link in original